# why spawn is little bit slower than direct command in nodejs

Tags: node.js, spawn

```
scriptExecution = spawn('python', ["-c", script_content])
```

when i execute this in nodejs it takes longer time to execute other than executing direct command which is fast.

there is 1-2 seconds delay in above process ,
how i can faster this `spawn('python', ["-c", script_content])`?

Comment: have you tried spawning from a child_process to avoid blocking the event loop?